# What are the replacements for javascript

Tags: javascript

What are the replacements for javescript.
I think JQuery in one of the good replacement for jave scripts though it is developed using Java script.
I want to know any other like this ..
Please give me any link or information on this

Answer (score 3):

jQuery *is* javascript. It does not "replace" javascript.

It is a library that makes some things very easy to express. There are many other javascript libraries, though jQuery is one of the best known.

Answer (score 2):

there are essentially no replacements for javascript, unless you (and you shouldn't!) count flash. there was vb-script, but it is a train wreck and fortunately not supported by any browser.

there are however a lot of excellent javascript libraries and frameworks for different purposes, e.g. jQuery, Mootools, sproutcore, knockout.js, backbone.js, prototype, script.acoul.us etc etc etc etc.

Comment: just a note: Mootools is not a library, is a framework (same as dojo ,yui and Ext JS)

Answer (score 1):

Try Dart or CoffeeScript, they do compile into Javascript because Javascript is the only widely available scripting language for web browsers without use of a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8255916/370103) has pointed out, jQuery is javascript. Here is a list of alternative javascript frameworks:

http://speckyboy.com/2008/04/01/top-10-javascript-frameworks-which-do-you-prefer/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery isn't replacement for JavaScript but only library that helps with faster code developing. Instead of JavaScript on Internet Explorer was (or maybe still is) possible to write scripts using VBScripts, but it's very unpopular until only IE can understand this code.

If you mean libraries there is:

- jQuery
- Prototype + Script.aculo.us
- Mootools
- Dojo
- ExtJs
- YUI
- etc.

Comparison of most of them you can find on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks).